# jsf richfaces a4j:region call render

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Using JSF2 and richfaces 4.

I have two regions in my form with multiple regions. I want to call render for another region. How can I do it?

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:region id="rg_1">
        <h:inputText id="field1" value="#{bean.field1}"/>   
    </a4j:region>
    <a4j:region id="rg_2">
        <a4j:commandLink action="#{mybean.resetBean} render="region1" />
    </a4j:region>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h:commandLink does not have `render` attribute , `f:ajax` does...

If you want to re render rg_1 from within rg_2 without page refresh (ajax)

do the following

```
<a4j:region id="rg_2">
    <a4j:commandLink action="#{mybean.resetBean}" render="rg_1"/>
</a4j:region>
```

also make sure that `mybean.resetBean` method is a `void` method or returns `null`

Comment: i tried this but commandlink bypassing all validation and going to action.

Comment: render is already mentioned but problem i had is it is submittion commandLink action="#{myBean.doSomething()}" bypassing all the jsf validation and going into action.

Comment: your original question used h:comandLink with render attribute... it was no validation issue related...